# side effects of ipv6 migration 

Tags: c, unix, ipv6, ipv4

Has any side effect migration of ipv6  for AF_LOCAL or  AF_UNiX address family ? ipv6 affects all system that were written for ipv4 exactly address family AF_INET ? i dont think so but i want to be sure about that can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The address families are completely independent, except that you can ask the IPv6 stack to forward some operations to the IPv4 stack. Applications that use AF_UNIX or AF_INET are generally unaffected by the transition.